# Excel Bar Graph Creation

Tags: excel, graph

I am trying to create a similar graph to the below where blue represents January, green represents February and grey represents March.

[image]

These are measured in a Red/Amber/Green rating and each section within the graph (there are 3 separate sections in the graph) represents areas such as the sales department, audit department, regulatory department, etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try exactly? Because there is a model just as the one you are looking for. [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chs82.png)

Comment: The same, however I need "Green", "Amber" and "Red" instead of the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My data and my grpah is like this:

[image]

The trick here is that your series must be vertical ranges:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I require, but the numbers are actually "Green", "Amber" or "Red". Is there a way that I can replace the numbers on the Y axis with Green, Amber and Red? Also, is there a way I can conditional format the graph to turn to the respective colours?

Comment: You mean the numbers from Vertical Axis? As far as I know, you can't. To draw a serie means you need numeric values. And to change the colors, just select each bar and apply the color you want

Comment: hmm, I think I can enter numeric values and change the titles in the y axis. Should work. Thank you